# How to insert keys from one database to another?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here is my code for inserting values from AdventureWorks to custom database.
I needed to transfer identifiers from AdventureWorks too but copy of identifiers are not allowed. So I thought using distinct with identifier would be enough, but I still get error about inserting duplicates.

If you could comment and tell me what I am doing wrong I would be very grateful.
Thank you!

Here is my full attempt:  https://pastebin.com/ZPniteh1

```
set identity_insert proizvodi ON

insert into proizvodi (ProizvodID, Sifra, Naziv, Kategorija, Podkategorija, Boja, Cijena, StanjeZaliha)
    select distinct 
        p.ProductID, p.ProductNumber,p.[Name], pc.[Name],psc.[Name], 
        p.Color, p.ListPrice, pii.Quantity
    from 
        AdventureWorks2017.Production.Product as p
    join 
        AdventureWorks2017.Production.ProductSubcategory as psc on psc.ProductSubcategoryID = p.ProductSubcategoryID
    join 
        AdventureWorks2017.Production.ProductCategory as pc on pc.ProductCategoryID = psc.ProductCategoryID
    inner join 
        AdventureWorks2017.Production.ProductInventory as pii on pii.ProductID = p.ProductID
    inner join 
        AdventureWorks2017.Sales.SalesOrderDetail as sod on sod.ProductID =  p.ProductID
    inner join 
        AdventureWorks2017.Sales.SalesOrderHeader as soh on soh.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
    inner join 
        AdventureWorks2017.Sales.SalesTerritory as st on st.TerritoryID = soh.TerritoryID
    inner join 
        AdventureWorks2017.Production.[Location] as l on l.LocationID = pii.LocationID
    where 
        st.[Group] ='Europe'
    order by 
        p.ProductID

    set identity_insert proizvodi OFF
```

Comment: What error are you getting "about inserting duplicates"? Run the Select statement and look at the data. You should see duplicates there.

Comment: oh i posted error message in pastebin link its           Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ProizvodID'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.proizvodi'. The duplicate key value --is (747).

Comment: Look at the column `pii.Quantity`. That is causing duplicate rows for a product  (`Product` table has 1:m relationship with `ProductInventory` table). Either remove that column if you don't need it or do an aggregate to get the total quantity of the product if that is what you want.